# Sharing remote memory

Tags: caching, shared-memory

I'm working on a project aimed to shared a portion of memory (DRAM) from one machine to another. I have two machines (M1 and M2, x86 Linux), M1 is able to access M2's memory by an NTB (Non-transparent Bridge), which is an PCIe address translation device connecting M1 and M2. Specifically, when M1 read/write its MMIO address 0x400000000, it will be redirected to M2's physical address 0x0, which is M2's system RAM. Based on this translation, I want to give a portion of M2's memory to M1.

I first took Linux memory hotplug to "offline" a section of memory (128MB) in M2 so that M2 doesn't use it anymore. At M1, I added this remote memory into M1's memory allocator and by checking the /proc/meminfo the additional 128MB is there. I further configure the M1 CPU's MTRR to make this 128MB uncachable, because the remote memory is not located in the local memory bus and is out of the cache coherence range. For example, if a disk is DMA to/from this remote memory, the M1's CPU's cache is not aware because the read/write does not go through M1's memory bus.

However, after putting some workload, my M1 hangs for no reason (no error in dmesg shown up). Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thank!

About memory hotplug:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-hotplug.txt

[image: My M1 and M2]

Comment: Hi William, have you solved this problem and if yes then how?

Comment: Hi Alex, I haven't solve this problem. But now I found that when I "online" a remote memory at M1 from the "offlined" memory at M2, the memory should be configured as "non-cacheable". This is due to the fact the remote memory is like memory in the MMIO space, the M1's cpu is not able to cache it.

Comment: Yes, when referring to someone else's memory which mapped to the physical address space of our processor (M1) - we need to mark this region it as Uncacheable or Write Combined, since PCI-Express is not cache-coherent interface. And the owner (M2) of the physical memory can leave caching enabled, for snooping mechanism.